# Windows 7 x64 .Net App Crash (works on everything else)

Tags: .net

I'm working on a .net application compiled for "Any CPU".  We have succesfully deployed the application to mutliple environments.  The only one giving us issue is Windows 7 x64 (it is crashing immediately complaining for BadImageFormatException).  When I run the application with Process Monitor attached, I get the following before it initiates Windows Error Reporting.

```
07:11.3 3544 RegOpenKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.3 3544 CreateFile C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\comctl32.dll NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.4 3544 CreateFile C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\comctl32.dll NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.4 3544 CreateFile C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\comctl32.dll NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.6 3544 RegOpenKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.6 3544 CreateFile C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\comctl32.dll NAME NOT FOUND
07:11.8 3544 RegOpenKey HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting NAME NOT FOUND
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Hans' point, check the following:

[Site Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/phoenix/thread/9a43e9a1-a744-4a1a-bb34-3604254c126b)

Essential part:

> You need to set Properties > Build >
>   Platform target to "x86". This will
>   force it to run in WoW64, so the
>   32-bit mixed model Phoenix assemblies
>   will load.